# DataStax C# Driver for Apache Cassandra for Materialized View

Tags: c#, linq, cassandra, materialized-views

Is there any LINQ statement for fetching data from Cassandra Materialized View using the C# Driver? I noticed the documentation does not mentioned about the new materialized view.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the query perspective, you can deal with Materialized Views in the same way you deal with tables.

In the case of Linq, this means defining mappings as a regular tables. Once the mapping is defined, you can use regular linq queries using the `Table<T>` constructor.

In case you need to query the MV metadata, you can use:

```
var mvMetadata =  cluster.Metadata.GetMaterializedView("ks1", "mv1");
```

Comment: Hi, do I have to define the mapping for the MV? Like how i did it for table? 
 For<Chat>()
                .TableName("chat")
                .PartitionKey(c => c.Id)
                .Column(c => c.Id, cm => cm.WithName("chat_id"))
                .Column(c => c.Type, cm => cm.WithName("type"))

Comment: @kevin.ng Correct